# How does gravity affect lower dimensional objects (1D - 2D)?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, string-theory, astrophysics, astronomy

How does gravity affect lower dimensional objects such as 1-dimensional strings or a BH's 2-dimensional event horizon, knowing already that it warps the 4D construct of space-time?

Comment: An event horizon is not a material object.

Comment: Perhaps .. but maybe the clumps of "strings" and bits of information that are in it are  ...

Answer (score 0):

The phenomenom of gravity as we know it results from the curvature of space-time caused by energy and pressure as predicted by the Einstein Equations. 1D, 2D and 3D objects all move through space and time and their motion through spacetime can be represented by their world lines (spacetime trajectories) in spacetime diagrams. It is spacetime that is curved, so objects "moving in it" will have their world lines affected. In other words, gravity isn't a property of the object but of spacetime itself. Being 1D, 2D or 3D does not change this.

Another thing is: Black Holes' event horizons aren't "2D objects". I don't understand why you would say that.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering João Vítor G. Lima ... This question was more a curiosity if a lower dimensional object had enough mass to warp the fabric of space-time .. how could a massive 1 dimensional object curve the 4D fabric of space-time ? .. would it only curve the 1 dimension it's in or propagate through the extra dimensions ? ... This is more the purpose of the question ..

Thank you for pointing my EH blunder .. I was pertaining more its constituents (strings/information) as objects and not itself as an object =)